# RESTful API design, differentiating PUT actions when updating a resource

Tags: json, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

This is a general RESTful API design question. We are trying to solve the following case with the most common approach possible.

We have a resource, let's say: /licenses/5123
The resource has an expiration date which needs to be updated to an expired state. Of course the easiest thing to do would be to just expose the expiration_date and have the client set it to the new date but that is not desired.
To update the resource, we're using PUT method and would like to specify the type of update this will be. In other words, is the update action 'expire' or 'extend' or 'whatever'.

I considered a few option:

1. implement custom http method - but I don't like extending HTTP protocol beyond its standards
2. add action url parameter and specify the value: PUT /licenses/5123?action=expire
3. since there are other params in the body of the request in JSON format, add action param into the JSON request.
4. implement custom http header for the type of update this is

Please share your opinion and/or provide any references to online resources that may be describing such cases. I can't imagine this is a unique case.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What about "sub-resources"? You could send `true` with `PUT /licenses/5123/expire`.

Comment: Interesting thought but expire is a verb which is to be avoided.

Comment: Well, just name the sub-resource as you want (`expiration_date` or `expired`).

Answer (score 2):

Generally option 2 and 3 are preferred. There is no real need to do something custom with HTTP actions or custom headers.

PUT is a reasonable action method for updating a license like you describe. Putting the details of the update in the JSON request body sounds reasonable (Option 3), and that's what I would do.

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 is my preferred choice.

I think going with option 2 has been my common best practice, it's clean, efficient and readable. Most of the time I strive for readability and maintainability over all else as I may not be the developer debugging, fixing or extending the code in the future.

Doing anything with either the HTTP protocol or headers always feels like a 'hack'. I think it's going above and beyond and will require more effort than the problem is most likely worth (which scraps solutions 1 and 4).

A potential issue with option 3 is that you could be confusing business logic with your data which leads to coupling and potential upgrade issues.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you prefer option 2 a bit more? It seems like that could get complicated quickly. Say you have a mailbox, and you can perform various actions on messages like marking them as read, changing their category, archiving them and choosing to be reminded later. One of the advantages of REST over RPC is that clients don't need to know procedure names, but doing this you still need to know them. At that point why not make them separate HTTP actions (e.g. `POST /messages/45434/archive`) to make the implementation a bit simpler (avoiding `if action == "..."`) and clearer?

Comment: My understanding is more that REST should be resource based. An action has no real reference to resource meta, it's merely defining an action to take place such as a change in workflow status. `/messages/45434/archive` to me isn't clear that you are archiving the given message, it reads more along the lines that archive would be some subset or sub-item. I think what I'm getting at is that RESTful paths shouldn't necessarily incorporate business logic, and interaction paths (workflow) which 'archive' would be.

Comment: If it's clearer my rule of thumb is that paths are nouns and parameter queries are verbs. Nouns and paths belong to, in some way, the model. Verbs belong to controllers and thus are instructions of how the model is treated, such as archiving. In terms of rest, your standard put and patch etc define a lower level interaction independsnt of any business logic e.g. create and edit.